# can't vnc to a machine connected through openvpn

Tags: vpn, vnc, openvpn

I am trying to set up a gaming vpn with OpenVPN and although the connection succeeds and we can see network shares, the broadcast packets don't go through the vpn connection.

Both the client and server configurations are using "dev tap" instead of tun.
My understanding is that i need tap to forward broadcast traffic over the vpn.

As a diagnostic step and to troubleshoot the issue better, I tried to vnc to the client machine through the OpenVPN connection by specifying the client's vpn ip address, but i'm unable to connect.

I'm unfamiliar with adding routes but I'm thinking that's what i might be missing.
I also noticed that the server open vpn configuration might be able to push routes to the clients.

How would I go about getting this to work?

The server is a Windows 7 machine and client is a Windows 8 machine.

I tried checking "Network Connections"->Advanced->Advanced Settings and making sure the VPN tap driver is listed first on the "Adapter and Bindings" tab under "Connections:"

What do I need to do to get vnc working over OpenVPN and getting lan gaming working over OpenVPN?